# how to perform parallel processing of gcp pubsub messages in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I have this code below that takes message from pubsub source topic -> transform it as per a template -> then publish the transformed message to a target topic.

But to improve performance I need to do this task in parallel.That is i need to poll 500 messages,and then transform it in parallel and then publish them to the target topic.

From the camel gcp component documentation I believe  maxMessagesPerPoll and concurrentConsumers parameter will do the job.Due to lack of documentation I am not sure how does it internally works.

I mean a) if I poll say 500 message ,will then it create 500 parallel route that will process the messages and publish it to the target topic b)what about ordering of the messages c) should I be looking at parallel processing EIPs as an alternative

etc.

The concept is not clear to me

Was go

```
// my route
private void addRouteToContext(final PubSub pubSub) throws Exception {

    this.camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("google-pubsub:{{gcp_project_id}}:{{pubsub.dead.letter.topic}}")
                    .useOriginalMessage().onPrepareFailure(new FailureProcessor()));




            /*
             * from topic
             */
            from("google-pubsub:{{gcp_project_id}}:" + pubSub.getFromSubscription() + "?"
                    + "maxMessagesPerPoll={{consumer.maxMessagesPerPoll}}&"
                    + "concurrentConsumers={{consumer.concurrentConsumers}}").
            /*
             * transform using the velocity
             */
            to("velocity:" + pubSub.getToTemplate() + "?contentCache=true").
            /*
             * attach header to the transform message
             */
            setHeader("Header ", simple("${date:now:yyyyMMdd}")).routeId(pubSub.getRouteId()).
            /*
             * log the transformed event
             */
            log("${body}").
            /*
             * publish the transformed event to the target topic
             */
            to("google-pubsub:{{gcp_project_id}}:" + pubSub.getToTopic());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you mention the `concurrentConsumers` option(let's say `concurrentConsumers=10`), you are asking Camel to create a thread pool of 10 threads, and each of those 10 threads will pick up a different message from the pub-sub queue and process them.

The thing to note here is that when you are specifying the concurrentConsumers option, the thread pool uses a fixed size, which means that a fixed number of active threads are waiting at all times to process incoming messages. So 10 threads(since I specified concurrentConsumers=10) will be waiting to process my messages, even if there aren't 10 messages coming in simultaneously.

Obviously, this is not going to guarantee that the incoming messages will be processed in the same order. If you are looking to have the messages in the same order, you can have a look at the [Resequencer EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/resequence-eip.html) to order your messages.

As for your third question, I don't think google-pubsub component allows a parallel processing option. You can make your own using the [Threads EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/threads-eip.html). This would definitely give more control over your concurrency.

Using Threads, your code would look something like this:

```
from("google-pubsub:project-id:destinationName?maxMessagesPerPoll=20")
// the 2 parameters are 'pool size' and 'max pool size'
.threads(5, 20)
.to("direct:out");
```

Comment: thank you Sneharghya ,you have very clearly explained the concept I was looking for.Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

> a) if I poll say 500 message ,will then it create 500 parallel route that will process the messages and publish it to the target topic

No, Camel does not create 500 parallel threads in this case. As you suspect, the number of concurrent consumer threads is set with `concurrentConsumers`. So if you define 5 `concurrentConsumers` with a `maxMessagesPerPoll` of 500, every consumer will fetch up to 500 messages and process them one after the other in a single thread. That is, you have 5 messages processed in parallel.

> what about ordering of the messages

As soon as you process messages in parallel, the order of messages is messed up. But this already happens with 1 Consumer when you got processing errors and they are detoured to your `deadLetterChannel` and reprocessed later.

> should I be looking at parallel processing EIPs as an alternative

Only if the `concurrentConsumers` option is not sufficient.

Comment: thank you burki ,you  have clearly explained the problem I had difficulty understanding.I am good now.Thanks a bunch –